# How can I print something(like pos(x,y)) without fixing __str__ in class in Python?

Tags: python

```
def main() :
    a = Shape()
    b = Shape("red")
    c = Shape("black",False,1,2)
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
    a.move(2,3)
    print(a)
    print(b.move(4,5))
    d = Circle("blue",False,10).move(3,4)
    print(d)
    e = Rectangle("blue",False,10,20)
    print(e.move(7,8))

class CPoint:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
    
    def setX(self):
        self.__x = x
    
    def setY(self):
        self.__y = y
    
    def getX(self):
        return self.__x
    
    def getY(self):
        return self.__y
    
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.__x += dx
        self.__y += dy
        return self
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'pos({CPoint.getX(self)}, {CPoint.getY(self)})'

class Shape(CPoint):
    def __init__(self, color="yellow", filled=True, x=0, y=0):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.__color = color
        self.__filled = filled
    
    def getColor(self):
        return self.__color
    
    def getFilled(self):
        return self.__filled
    
    def setColor(self):
        self.__color = color
    
    def setFilled(self):
        self.__filled = filled
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'pos({CPoint.getX(self)}, {CPoint.getY(self)})({Shape.getColor(self)},{Shape.getFilled(self)})'

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color="yellow", filled=True, radius=0):
        super().__init__(color, filled)
        self.__radius = radius
    
    def area(self):
        fullArea = 3.14*((self.__radius)**2)
        return fullArea
    
    def setRadius(self):
        self.__radius = radius
    
    def getRadius(self):
        return self.__radius
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'({Shape.getColor(self)},{Shape.getFilled(self)})'+f'(radius = {Circle.getRadius(self)})'

class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color="yellow", filled=True, width=0, height=0):
        super().__init__(color, filled)
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height
    
    def area(self):
        fullArea = self.__width*self.__height
        return fullArea
    
    def setWidth(self):
        self.__width = width
    
    def setHeight(self):
        self.__height = height
    
    def getWidth(self):
        return self.__width
    
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.__height
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'({Shape.getColor(self)},{Shape.getFilled(self)})({Rectangle.getWidth(self)},{Rectangle.getHeight(self)})'

main()
```

I want to get the answer like this:

```
pos(0,0)(yellow,True)
pos(0,0)(red,True)
pos(1,2)(black,False)
pos(2,3)(yellow,True)
pos(4,5)(red,True)
pos(3,4)(blue,False)(radius = 10)
pos(7,8)(blue,False)(10,20)
```

but I got like this:

```
pos(0, 0)(yellow,True)
pos(0, 0)(red,True)
pos(1, 2)(black,False)
pos(2, 3)(yellow,True)
pos(4, 5)(red,True)
(blue,False)(radius = 10)
(blue,False)(10,20)
```

last two get no pos(x, y).

Is there any way that I can get the right answer without fixing **str** in Circle(Shape),Rectangle(Shape)? (Changing **str** in class Shape(CPoint) is possible)
I think I need to change some code in class Cpoint to display pos(x, y) for the right answer and try something but didn't got proper one. What should I change from this code?

+All variable must be used as private variable for learning purpose.

Comment: You are trying to inherit the private variables of another class which seems to be the main problem

Comment: You forgot to duplicate the `CPoint.__str__` code in your `Shape` subclasses. Note that you'll probably want to use `super().__str__` in some way to simplify this.

Comment: Also, this is extremely non-idiomatic code. If you want to provide getter and setter methods, use `property` to define them. But since your setters do nothing except directly set the underlying values (no checks or modifications), you may as well just use the attributes directly. (The nice thing about properties is that they can replace existing attributes without requiring any changes.)

Comment: Um then where can I put CPoint.__str__ ??

Comment: `return f'{super().__str__()}...'`.